# Optional UIImage array is nil after appending images

Tags: ios, swift, foreach

I have created an optional `UIImage` array as the following

```
var images: [UIImage]?
```

Then I have a function that receives as parameter an `UIImage` array:

```
func process(_ images: [UIImage] {
    images.forEach {
        self.images?.append($0)
    }
    print("images nil?:", self.images == nil)
}
```

Somehow this function prints that my `self.images` is nil, even after appending objects to it; but if I change my `forEach` iteration to simply:

```
self.images = images
```

It now doesn't recognize that the global variable is nil.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Where do you allocate the array ? self.images = [] or self.images = Array() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your array like this:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
```

Append the whole array at once like:

```
func process(_ images: [UIImage]) {
    self.images.append(contentsOf: images)
    print(self.images)
}
```

No need to make your array optional. Since if there is no images in the array it would be empty. Check for array count instead of making it optional.

Comment: What if I later need to append more images to the array, `contentsOf` will work as the regular `forEach` iteration?

Comment: Yes it well. Note that in the initialization, you have make the array mutable by using var. You can append it whenever you want.

Comment: I didn't knew we could append chunks of objects at once. Really good ;)

Comment: Since you are not performing any other check, you are just append all of the contents of the incoming array to the other array you don't need to iterate using foreach loop. Just append everything you got.

Comment: @Sh_Khan this answer provides the same resolution as the others, Plus a code cleanup avoiding unnecessary iterations, so if it fulfills my purposes in a better way, it’s up to me, the questioner to accept the best option for my case. This is a helper community

Comment: @Sh_Khan and the answers came in like a storm, not with noticeable time difference; but that’s my opinion. And by the time I had the possibility to accept an answer , all the present answers were already posted.

Comment: @Sh_Khan you shouldn't try convincing anyone which answer to accept. OP has every right to accept any of the answers if there are more than one regardless of when each one was posted. The accepted answer should be the one that helps OP most, which isn't necessarily the one that was posted first, but it's completely up to OP to decide which one to accept.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank You. Somehow people don't understand that this is a helper community and they confuse it with a points race maybe. (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialise an array.

```
var images: [UIImage]? = []
```

Comment: Can I initialize it optionally? like `[UIImage]?()` with the parenthesis after the `?` I really didn't knew that :O

Comment: Yes, you can, check answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have never initialised your images array. Before appending, please do this:

```
images = [UIImage]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to do this

```
var images = [UIImage]()
func process(_ images: [UIImage] {
    self.images = images
}
```